# How to use d3.force for dynamic, non-overlapping labeling of a scatterplot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

Edit: Is it possible to import d3.force into my react component? if not, then I may be struggling with this for no reason.

From googling the problem (how to add labels to a scatterplot without them overlapping), the answer appears to be d3.force (at least this one of the answers), and it is the answer that I'd like to try to wrap my head around.

I've created a very small, simple example with ~15 circles and their corresponding text labels, which are currently placed 6 pixels right and 3 pixels below the marker. The result is a messy graph of over-lapping label names.

```js
const myData = [
  {x:25, y:30, name:"tommy"},
  {x:8, y:12, name:"joey"},
  {x:92, y:107, name:"nicky"},
  {x:85, y:50, name:"peter"},
  {x:65, y:80, name:"mickie"},
  {x:65, y:80, name:"gregie"},
  {x:54, y:6, name:"tammie"},
  {x:102, y:42, name:"benny"},
  {x:66, y:45, name:"dennie"},
  {x:81, y:44, name:"jerryi"},
  {x:127, y:36, name:"garrie"},
  {x:62, y:30, name:"frankie"},
  {x:157, y:55, name:"joeiyei"},
  {x:157, y:62, name:"nickaie"},
  {x:58, y:105, name:"tommie"}
]

d3.select('#mySvg')
  .selectAll('circle')
  .data(myData)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', d => d.x)
  .attr('cy', d => d.y)
  .attr('r', 6)
  .attr('fill', 'blue')
  
d3.select('#mySvg')
  .selectAll('text')
  .data(myData)
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .attr('x', d => d.x + 6)
  .attr('y', d => d.y + 3)
  .attr('font-size', '0.8em')
  .text(d => d.name)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg id="mySvg">
```

I'm struggling to see where to get started with the d3.force documentation. Should I convert the whole graph into a force graph? I don't mind some points overlapping, and in my data (and in this example), some points have the exact same x,y coordinates.

Additionally, is it possible to have a light grey line connecting between the label and the points, so that there is no confusion between which label corresponds to which point?

Apologies if this has been asked before. In my efforts to search for an answer to this question, I found a few graphs that were entirely force graphs (which I don't think I want). Any help is appreciated here!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, do not turn the entire chart into a force directed chart. Given what I'm seeing in your code, the precise vertical and horizontal positions of the dots encode an information, which has to be accurately transmitted to the user. A force directed chart will be, by its very definition, something that cannot guarantee such precision.

You could use a force simulation to avoid the collision of the labels, that is, applying the simulation only for the texts and not for the points. That's not hard to do, but even so, I'd advise to not do so. The reason here is simple: you have text labels, not graphic elements like a circle. Those texts cannot be freely rotated, and should not be rotated (that makes the reading harder).

Therefore, given the texts should be horizontally presented, the approach I like most in such situations is playing with `text-anchor`. Together with enlarging the scatter the most you can for making the best use of the available area (here I'm using a simple linear scale), that approach can be quite effective. And it's very simple:

First, we create an array of names to be shown at the left of the dots:

```
const namesToLeft = ["dennie", "gregie"];
```

Then, we change the `text-anchor`:

```
.attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
    return namesToLeft.indexOf(d.name) > -1 ? "end" : "start"
})
```

Here is the demo:

```js
const myData = [{
    x: 25,
    y: 30,
    name: "tommy"
  },
  {
    x: 8,
    y: 12,
    name: "joey"
  },
  {
    x: 92,
    y: 107,
    name: "nicky"
  },
  {
    x: 85,
    y: 50,
    name: "peter"
  },
  {
    x: 65,
    y: 80,
    name: "mickie"
  },
  {
    x: 65,
    y: 80,
    name: "gregie"
  },
  {
    x: 54,
    y: 6,
    name: "tammie"
  },
  {
    x: 102,
    y: 42,
    name: "benny"
  },
  {
    x: 66,
    y: 45,
    name: "dennie"
  },
  {
    x: 81,
    y: 44,
    name: "jerryi"
  },
  {
    x: 127,
    y: 36,
    name: "garrie"
  },
  {
    x: 62,
    y: 30,
    name: "frankie"
  },
  {
    x: 157,
    y: 55,
    name: "joeiyei"
  },
  {
    x: 157,
    y: 62,
    name: "nickaie"
  },
  {
    x: 58,
    y: 105,
    name: "tommie"
  }
];

var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 160])
  .range([0, 300]);

const namesToLeft = ["dennie", "gregie"];

d3.select('#mySvg')
  .selectAll('circle')
  .data(myData)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', d => scale(d.x))
  .attr('cy', d => scale(d.y))
  .attr('r', 6)
  .attr('fill', 'blue')

d3.select('#mySvg')
  .selectAll('text')
  .data(myData)
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
    return namesToLeft.indexOf(d.name) > -1 ? "end" : "start"
  })
  .attr('x', d => scale(d.x) + (namesToLeft.indexOf(d.name) > -1 ? -6 : 6))
  .attr('y', d => scale(d.y) + 3)
  .attr('font-size', '0.8em')
  .text(d => d.name)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg id="mySvg" width="400" height="300">
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to avoid force graphs. My full dataset changes frequently and has many points though, so I will try to modify your suggestion with a way to calculate, based on x,y coordinate, which names overlap so I can switch them up like this.